# Parsing json.dumps - Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

I have a call to an API that returns the following JSON:

```
{
"trades": [
    {
        "stopLoss": 154.79, 
        "takeProfit": 151.79, 
        "price": 153.784, 
        "side": "sell", 
        "trailingStop": 0, 
        "instrument": "GBP_JPY", 
        "time": "2016-06-21T18:20:24.000000Z", 
        "units": 25, 
        "id": 10297636517, 
        "trailingAmount": 0
    }
]
}
```

I'm having trouble parsing so that I only return the "id" and the "price".  For reasons I don't understand yet, i can add `['trades']` after `tradeId=response` and it will drill down to just this, as expected.  But i cannot get it whittled down to just "id" and "price".  How could I go about parsing the data, and is json.dumps the optimal method?  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
{
        "stopLoss": 154.79, 
        "takeProfit": 151.79, 
        "price": 153.784, 
        "side": "sell", 
        "trailingStop": 0, 
        "instrument": "GBP_JPY", 
        "time": "2016-06-21T18:20:24.000000Z", 
        "units": 25, 
        "id": 10297636517, 
        "trailingAmount": 0
    }
```

code:

```
response = oanda.get_trades(account_id)

def transactions():
    while response:
        tradeId = response
        ids = tradeId
        line = json.dumps(ids, indent=4)
        print line
        return
print transactions()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **json.loads()** to parse the json.

```
import json
response = '{"trades": [{"stopLoss": 154.79, "takeProfit": 151.79, "price": 153.784, "side": "sell", "trailingStop": 0, "instrument": "GBP_JPY", "time": "2016-06-21T18:20:24.000000Z", "units": 25, "id": 10297636517, "trailingAmount": 0}]}'

def transactions():
    json_tree = json.loads(response)
    trade_list = json_tree['trades']
    trade = trade_list[0]
    return (trade['id'], trade['price'])

print transactions()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer.  I was trying just `['trades']['id']` and not 
`['trades'][0]['id']`..  thanks